# Objective-C: BOOL being returned as (null) using containsObject

Tags: objective-c, null, boolean

I'm storing an `NSMutableArray` in `NSUserDefaults` using `dispatch_once` in `AppDelegate`.

**Code** in `AppDelegate.m`'s `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
static dispatch_once_t once;
dispatch_once(&once, ^ {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:@"seenTutorial"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
});
```

I know there's nothing wrong with the actual array as it is printing its contents properly when I try printing it to the console. For example:

**Code** in `viewDidAppear`

```
NSMutableArray *usersWhoHaveSeenTutorial = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"seenTutorial"];
[usersWhoHaveSeenTutorial addObject:currentUserID];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:usersWhoHaveSeenTutorial forKey:@"seenTutorial"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
NSLog(@"ARRAY WITH USER IDs: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"seenTutorial"]);
```

**Output**:

```
2014-10-16 16:14:05.720 Unitu[71969:4552403] ARRAY WITH USER IDs: (
    5184
)
```

However, if I try to check if an element is contained inside an array using `containsObject:`, the boolean value is assigned `(null)` instead of `YES` or `NO`.

**Code** in `viewDidAppear`:

```
BOOL hasSeenTutorial = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"seenTutorial"] containsObject:currentUserID];
NSLog(@"Has user seen tutorial? %@", hasSeenTutorial);
```

**Output**:

```
2014-10-16 15:59:38.102 App[71662:4542538] Has user seen tutorial? (null)
```

I feel like there's a flaw in my logic that I can't seem to figure out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read up on format specifiers (see the link in the docs for `NSString stringWithFormat:`).

`BOOL` is not an object. You can't use `%@` to log it. Use `%d` instead.

```
NSLog(@"Has user seen tutorial? %d", hasSeenTutorial);
```

This will log `0` (NO) or `1` (YES).

Or you can do:

```
NSLog(@"Has user seen tutorial? %@", hasSeenTutorial ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

This will log the string based on the `BOOL` value.

BTW - your original code logs `(null)` because a `BOOL` value of `NO` is really `0`. And using `%@` is looking for an object pointer. The `0` of the `BOOL` value is interpreted as a `nil` pointer since `nil` is also really just `0`. If your `BOOL` value was `YES`, the app would likely crash since the app would attempt to call the `description` method on whatever object happens to be at memory address `1` (the value for `YES`).